# Python login into IMDB pro

Tags: python, authentication, imdb

I would like to download the top 5000 celebs in imdb's starmeter ratings, however to do this I need to be logged into the webserver (for imdb pro) I have no idea how to do this programatically.  Is there an imdb api which manages a login to imdb pro or does someone have some code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not played with this, but there is IMDb 0.1.2 over at PyPi
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IMDb. .

Answer (score 0):

The PyPi link appears to be dead, try this one:

[python-imdb](https://github.com/nandhp/python-imdb)